# Finding the eigenvectors of a matrix that has one eigenvalue of multiplicity three

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a simple question, which hopefully has a quick answer. I have a given matrix A, such that

\begin{equation} A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{equation}

Since it's fairly straightforward, I'll just state that the eigenvalue of this matrix is $\lambda = 1$ with algebraic multiplicity $3$. To find the eigenvectors of this matrix, all I have to do is find the kernel of $(A-\lambda I)$. Thus,

\begin{equation} (A-\lambda I) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} -(1)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation}

The kernel of this matrix, according to my work and Wolfram Alpha, is $Ker(A-\lambda I) = \{(-1, 0, 1)^T, (0, 1, 0)^T\}$.

However, MATLAB and my calculator say that the eigenvectors are $(0, 1, 0)^T, (0,-1,0)^T,  (0, -1, 0)^T$.

My question, then, is where did I go wrong? I looked through my book, and it does indeed cover eigenvalues with multiplicity, but it doesn't treat them any differently than the case with no multiplicity. Did I commit an algebraic error somewhere?

NOTE: I should be a little more precise. Find the kernel of $(A-\lambda I) gives the eigenspace of the corresponding eigenvalue, which happens to be composed of eigenvectors.

Comment: The vectors $(0,1,0)^T$ and $(0,-1,0)^T$ are proportional, so it's strange to include them both and one twice.

Comment: The *independent* eigenvectors are just those two that you found. Behind the scenes in Matlab, it is *trying* to find 3 independent eigenvectors and failing, in that the third eigenvector and the second eigenvector are converging to one another. It proceeds this way because it is impossible to detect nondiagonalizability without carrying out calculations in exact arithmetic, because diagonalizable matrices are *dense* in the space of all matrices. You might try using the jordan command in Matlab (which uses exact arithmetic, and hence is extremely slow in large problems) to see this effect.

Comment: @Ian Interesting. That's good to know. Also, why, then, does the Kernel differ from the first two eigenvectors produced by MATLAB? I multiplied $A$ by the vectors in my Kernel, and they are indeed eigenvectors. Furthermore, The first two eigenvectors of of the ones MATLAB found are linearly dependent, so it seems like it really only found one eigenvector.

Comment: @Mlagma I am not sure about that part, apparently eig runs into trouble with this matrix, in that it is actually only detecting *one* independent eigenvector. Yet you can check that $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is indeed an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. The jordan command correctly finds both independent eigenvectors along with the "generalized eigenvector" $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Ian That's somewhat irritating that $eig$ runs into this problem. However, it's good to know its limitations - and to know that I was doing the problem right. As a side note, I tested it on Wolfram Alpha, and it finds the correct eigenvectors, but it also tries to find a third eigenvector. The third "eigenvector", though, is simply the zero vector so it can be ignored.

Comment: An interesting experiment: if you replace all the $0$s in your matrix with a small positive number and run eig, you will get three ("barely") independent eigenvectors with eigenvalues of essentially $1$ (but "barely" distinct). Two of them will be essentially your $[0,1,0]^T$. The other will be essentially your $[-1,0,1]^T$. This probably shows why Matlab can't find the other one when you send the entries back to zero: somehow its contribution is "drowned out" by the other eigenvector having multiplicity 2.

Comment: Also, if I've answered everything, then I will combine these comments into an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @Ian Of course, go head and post it as an answer.

Comment: @Ian Quick question, you said one of the eigenvectors has multiplicity 2. Do you mean in regard to the multiplicity MATLAB produces, or in regard to the actual eigenvectors - since $\lambda = 1$ has algebraic multiplicity 3, and geometric multiplicity 2?

Comment: In your actual matrix, there is only one eigenvalue, of algebraic multiplicity $3$ and geometric multiplicity $2$. In a nearby diagonalizable matrix (e.g. the matrix where the $0$s are replaced by $10^{-6}$), there are three distinct eigenvalues, which are all very nearly $1$. Two of them have very nearly the same eigenvectors, which are very close to $[0,1,0]^T$. The other one has an eigenvector very close to $[-1,0,1]^T$.

Comment: Actually, it turns out to be even worse than what I described, but I think a proper explanation would have to pass to the SVD. (In some sense $[0,1,0]^T$ is a "symmetric eigenvector" which makes it "more  stable than" $[-1,0,1]^T$.) If you're interested, feel free to post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, and Matlab is being problematic. Here's some discussion of why this isn't so surprising:

Defective eigenvalue problems are numerically problematic. This is because diagonalizable matrices are dense in the space of all matrices. Consequently an arbitrarily small arithmetic error can make a nondiagonalizable matrix into a diagonalizable matrix. So unless you use a solver which uses exact arithmetic, your solver will assume that your matrix is diagonalizable and attempt to find three independent eigenvectors.

The problem occurs when, in the background, some of the approximate eigenvectors converge to one another. If you use a solver with exact arithmetic, then no issues occur. Indeed, Matlab's jordan command gives the correct output for this problem.

Apparently Matlab's eig command is having trouble with this problem in particular. One thing that makes this problem especially bad is that the eigenvector Matlab is successfully finding gets split into two independent vectors when you perturb your matrix into a diagonalizable matrix (for instance by replacing all of the $0$s with $10^{-6}$). Somehow this causes that eigenvector to get weighted much more heavily, and makes the other one "invisible" to the algorithm used by eig.